# Can not set query string in functional tests

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I'm trying to test my API methods with query string set. However, I can not. Tests just ignore my query string, making it empty in the API method bodies.

I use Symfony 4.2.5 and PHPUnit 6.5.14

```php
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class TodosControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function testGetTodos()
    {
        $c = static::createClient();
        $c->request('GET', '/todo?length=0');
        $this->assertEquals(Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST, $c->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
```

I want to get `/todo` working with `length=0` but it does not.

```php
public function getTodos()
{
    $r = $this->getRequest();
    var_dump($r->query->all()); // empty array
    var_dump($_GET);            // empty array
```

Comment: Is the `getTodos()` in a controller? I wonder about how you get the request - usually you could add it as a controller action parameter, like so: `public function getTodos(Request $request)`. If you can I would try that first. What exactly is the `$this->getRequest()` doing?

About reading the `$_GET` superglobal - I believe test request does not populate into those, as I understood [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/19380#issuecomment-233340765)

Comment: Yes, `getTodos` is a controller method. Your comment answers my question. The problem was that I use request object built from `Request::createFromGlobals()`. However, globals are empty in tests, so I use request object containing nothing. If anyone is interested why I chose this method instead of obtaining request object as a parameter in a controller method, it was an attempt to parse JSON body and put it in the request object if Content-Type is application/json and the request body is a valid JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I recreate request object from globals which are empty in tests (`Request::createFromGlobals()` in constructor and `$this->getRequest()` in methods). The only correct way to obtain request object is to get it from method parameters:

```php
public function getTodos(Request $r)
{
    var_dump($r->query->all()); // parsed query string array
```